# MVC4 Bundling IncludeDirectory - file paths wrong

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, bundler

I'm having an issue adding bundling to an existing project. The problem is the output path when rendering to the page. I am including directories with subfolders traversing them looking for *.js like so:

```
BundleTable.Bundles.Add(
    new ScriptBundle("~/ui/js")
        .IncludeDirectory("~/ui/lib/", "*.js", true)
        .IncludeDirectory("~/ui/class/", "*.js", true)
        .IncludeDirectory("~/ui/modules/", "*.js", true)
);
```

So for example, under /ui/lib/ I have subfolders for the libraries, but what is being output to the browser is src="/ui/lib/file.js" when it should be /ui/lib/folder/file.js

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong, I have a project that uses the same code as above but works fine for rendering the correct file paths.

It may be related, but when I switch to release mode and things get concat/minified the dynamic path renders the 404 page also.

Would appreciate any help/ideas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think if you check your assembly references you will see that you are using

```
Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization version 1.1.1
```

If yes, uninstall it and choose "stable only" in nuget GUI instead of "include prelease" and reinstall it.  Should then be version 1.1.0.

Let me know if the issue goes away when you downgrade.

Thanks.

UPDATE:

The solution is to go to `1.1.0` as `1.1.1` has an issue in this regard. Note that `1.1.1` is now falgged stable (as of 10/10/2013). You will need to uninstall that package and run the following from the Nuget command line:

`Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization -Version 1.1.0`

Comment: Awesome man! I did need 1.1.0 - I did run into a little issue however. It seems 1.1.1 is flagged as stable right now! So it is the one installed by default. I had to uninstall it and install 1.1.0 from the command line using: `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization -Version 1.1.0` - Your answer helped get me there, thank you! Could you update your answer to account for 1.1.1 being stable with the command that can be used to install 1.1.0?

Comment: This is also a problem in MVC 5 - http://aspnetoptimization.codeplex.com/workitem/105